# Hybrid Encryption for GET request using React and Node JS

Tags: encryption, rsa, hybrid

I managed to to POST/UPDATE and DEL request from React application (from different microfrontend using Webpack 5), to multiple backend application (microservice) written in Node JS.
Each data is encrypted using a key created with symmetric key. The symmetric key is also encrypted using Public key from client. Then both encrypted data and key sent to server to be decrypted in the server for storing.

What about GET request ? How do I do reverse encryption of data sent from server to be read on the client, especially I have multiple micro front end client. Do I create multiple RSA pair keys for each micro front end, with private keys stored in each client, public key to be sent along with GET request to the server ?

Comment: *Then both encrypted data and key sent to server to be decrypted in the server for storing.* It's already encrypted using TLS, encrypting it again doesn't make it twice as secure.

Comment: True for data that's sent from client to server.I'm talking about data sent from server to client using hybrid encryption.

Comment: TLS encrypts data in both directions.